# Is there a way to overlay Haskell GNUPlot plots on top of each other?

Tags: haskell, gnuplot

I'm using GNUPlot.Simple for Haskell and am trying to plot 2 charts on top of each other.
One is using the filled curve format, one is a normal line.
The code I am using is :

```
plotListsStyle []  [ (( defaultStyle {plotType =  FilledCurves} ) , ( zip3 [1,2,3] [2,3,4] [0,1,2] )), ((PlotStyle {plotType = Lines, lineSpec = CustomStyle [PointSize 0.1] }), (zip [1,2,3] [1,2,3]) )]
```

They work fine when I do them separately as:

```
plotListsStyle []  [ (( defaultStyle {plotType =  FilledCurves} ) , ( zip3 [1,2,3] [2,3,4] [0,1,2] ))]
```

and

```
plotListsStyle [] [((PlotStyle {plotType = Lines, lineSpec = CustomStyle [PointSize 0.1] }), (zip [1,2,3] [1,2,3]) )]
```

but not when done together.
Is it possible to overlay GNUPlots on top of each other?

Comment: Not an answer to the question, rather an observation. You would get better results, I suspect, writing the data to CSV and then using R or Pandas to process the results.

Comment: @FrancisKing possibly, but this is awkward to use and particularly bad to automate. Haskell-GNUPlot is itself already a bit of a hack like this, but at least it's properly controlled from within Haskell. Fully native plotting solutions like [Chart](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Chart) and [dynamic-plot](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dynamic-plot) have a lot of advantages in principle, though of course they don't have the benefit of as much work put in them by all the people using Python or R for plotting stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just need to trick the type checker by supplying some extra data that GNUPlot doesn't actually need.  Try something like:

```
import Graphics.Gnuplot.Simple

main = do
  plotListsStyle []
    [ ( defaultStyle {plotType =  FilledCurves}
      , zip3 [1::Double,2,3] [2::Double,3,4] [0::Double,1,2] )
    , ( PlotStyle {plotType = Lines, lineSpec = CustomStyle [PointSize 0.1] }
      , zip3 [1::Double,2,3] [1::Double,2,3] (repeat 0))
--                                           ^^^^^^^^^^
--                            Provide this useless extra data
    ]
```

The problem here is that `plotListsStyle` takes a list of tuples, and -- as with all Haskll lists -- all the tuples need to be of the same type, so you can't have data of type `[(Double,Double,Double)]` in one tuple and data of type `[(Double,Double)]` in another.